# Let ss be a std::stringstream. How to specify a concept for (ss<<some_type).str() is a std::string?

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

Let ss be a std::stringstream. How to specify a concept for (ss << some_type).str() is a std::string?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

namespace detail {
    template< class T, class U >
    concept SameHelper = std::is_same_v<T, U>;
}

template< class T, class U >
concept same_as = detail::SameHelper<T, U> && detail::SameHelper<U, T>;

template<typename T>
concept ssToStr = requires(T a, std::stringstream ss) {
    { (ss << a).str() } -> same_as<std::string>;
};

void call(ssToStr auto obj)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::cout << (ss << obj).str() << std::endl;

}

int main() 
{
    call("Hi");
    return 0;
}
```

[You can check online that the code does not compile.](https://godbolt.org/z/ewbBUB)
The first part of the error messages reads:

```
<source>:25:5: error: no matching function for call to 'call'

    call("Hi");

    ^~~~
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Mooing Duck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/845092/mooing-duck) I was able to get the code running. The running code reads:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

template<typename T>
concept ssToStr = requires(T a, std::stringstream ss) {
    { ss << a };
};

void call(ssToStr auto obj)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << obj;
    std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
}

int main() 
{
    call("Hi");
    return 0;
}
```

[You can run the code online](https://godbolt.org/z/sdM6_g)

Answer (score 3):

You're missing `#include <sstream>`

Fixing that gives the error message that contains:

```
<source>:14:17: note: because '(ss << a).str()' would be invalid: no member named 'str' in 'std::basic_ostream<char>'

    { (ss << a).str() } -> same_as<std::string>;
```

Which tells you that `(ss << obj)` evaluates to a `std::ostream`, which does not have a `.str()` member. All you have to check is that `ss<<a` compiles, and you already know that `ss.str()` results in a string, so you don't need that in your constraint.

Unfortunately, I don't know enough about constraints to create the working code for you.

Comment: Thanks, with your help I was able to get the code running.