# Concept to check if a class is streamable

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

How can I implemented a concept to check if a type is streamable using std::ostream? Possibly using constraints/`requires`, but the info I find through google is either very elementary or can as well be klingon.

```
template<typename T> concept bool can_ostream()
{
    return check_if_operator<<(..)_is_in_T;  or something like this
}
```

so I can use it e.g.:

```
template<can_ostream T> struct X { ... }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concepts are very new. I'm about 90% sure that the following is the correct way to do this but I couldn't get it to compile on clang:

```
template <typename T>
concept Streamable = 
  requires(std::ostream &os, T value) {
    { os << value } -> std::convertible_to<std::ostream &>;
  };
```

---

To get around the limitations of clang, you could do this:

```
template <typename T>
concept Stream = std::is_convertible_v<T, std::ostream &>;

template <typename T>
concept Streamable =
  requires(std::ostream &os, T value) {
    { os << value } -> Stream;
  };
```

---

Another approach is to define a trait without concepts and then define the concept in terms of the trait. But then you're sacrificing one of the benefits of concepts which is the error messages.

```
// This is how we used to do things back in my day

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_streamable : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_streamable<T, std::enable_if_t<
  std::is_convertible_v<
    decltype(std::declval<std::ostream &>() << std::declval<T>()),
    std::ostream &
  >
>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
concept Streamable = is_streamable<T>::value;
```

---

For compilers that don't support concepts, you can just use the `is_streamable` trait. The above definition is C++17 but with some tweaks, this can be done in C++11.

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_streamable : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_streamable<T, typename std::enable_if<
  std::is_convertible<
    decltype(std::declval<std::ostream &>() << std::declval<T>()),
    std::ostream &
  >::value
>::type> : std::true_type {};
```

**Concepts are just sugar.** Concepts give you better error messages and they're easier to write than the template stuff above. AFAIK, they don't let you do anything that you couldn't already do in C++17.

---

I realised that the trait could be simplified a little bit. I'm once again using C++11 to keep things portable.

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_streamable : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_streamable<T, decltype(
  static_cast<std::ostream &>(std::declval<std::ostream &>() << std::declval<T>())
)> : std::true_type {};
```

Since I'm editing the answer again, I'll say that **concepts are just sugar!** C++20 is a big one. It's going to be a while before support is widespread enough to make it feasible to use concepts in production.

Comment: nice try, but no luck, I'm still hacking at it; The solution would be the same as testing if some function is defined for a given type & I cannot find any examples (maybe just searching wrong) (then also we could be right and the compiler still need to catch-up :)

Comment: @slashmais You could use the `is_streamable` trait without concepts just fine. With some minor tweaks, it will work with C++14 or C++11. Using concepts this early is probably not a great idea.

Comment: Adding `template<typename T> concept bool Can_Stream() {  return is_streamable<T>::value; };` to your edit makes it work as expected. Thank you! (maybe just sugar, but it fits nicely)

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax for the concept you want reads:

```
template <typename T>
concept Streamable = requires(std::ostream os, T value) {
    { os << value };
  };
```

With respect to concepts clang is lagging behind gcc. So I recommend using gcc.
[You can run the following code online](https://godbolt.org/z/Stdppi):

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
concept Streamable = requires(std::ostream os, T value) {
    { os << value };
  };

void call(Streamable auto obj)
{
    std::ostream os(nullptr);
    os.rdbuf(std::cout.rdbuf());
    os << obj << std::endl;
    //do stuff with os ...
}

int main() 
{
    call("Hi");
    call(3.14159);
    return 0;
}
```

[See also this post for a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60552631/let-ss-be-a-stdstringstream-how-to-specify-a-concept-for-sssome-type-str).

Comment: Thanks, I have that commented in my source for when my distro eventually upgrades gcc/g++ to handle c++20. Currently need to return bool when defining the concept, so until then will be using long version.